# ElasticSearch _bulk call resulting in "socket hang up" despite small size

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using elastical to connect to ElasticSearch via node.js.

In the process of profiling my app with Nodetime to attempt to improve performance, I noticed something odd. My ElasticSearch "PUT" requests to _bulk index are frequently resulting in a "socket hang up". Furthermore, these calls are taking huge amounts of CPU time.

I'm capping each _bulk index request @ 10 items to index, and as you can see, the content-length of the requests does not even reach 50Kb, so it is hard to imagine that the size is an issue. Yet, the response time is > 60 seconds and the CPU time is >10+ seconds! Yikes!!

[image]

In attempts to debug, I started running ElasticSearch in the foreground. I noticed this strange error:

```
    [2013-02-27 11:42:39,188][WARN ][index.gateway.s3         ] [Lady Mandarin] [network][1] failed to read commit point [commit-f34]
java.io.IOException: Failed to get [commit-f34]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.blobstore.support.AbstractBlobContainer.readBlobFully(AbstractBlobContainer.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.blobstore.BlobStoreIndexShardGateway.buildCommitPoints(BlobStoreIndexShardGateway.java:847)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.blobstore.BlobStoreIndexShardGateway.doSnapshot(BlobStoreIndexShardGateway.java:188)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.blobstore.BlobStoreIndexShardGateway.snapshot(BlobStoreIndexShardGateway.java:160)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$2.snapshot(IndexShardGatewayService.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$2.snapshot(IndexShardGatewayService.java:265)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.snapshot(RobinEngine.java:1090)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.snapshot(InternalIndexShard.java:496)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService.snapshot(IndexShardGatewayService.java:265)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$SnapshotRunnable.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by: Status Code: 404, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: ..., AWS Error Code: NoSuchKey, AWS Error Message: The specified key does not exist., S3 Extended Request ID: ....
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:548)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:288)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2632)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:811)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:717)
    at org.elasticsearch.cloud.aws.blobstore.AbstractS3BlobContainer$1.run(AbstractS3BlobContainer.java:73)
```

I'm aware that I'm using a deprecated gateway (the S3 bucket gateway). However, given that I have multiple servers running on the Amazon Cloud which need to share data (I use ElasticSearch for caching), I don't see any alternative until the ElasticSearch team releases a replacement for the S3 Bucket Gateway...

Other than this problem with the _bulk calls, I'm not seeing any problems. Searches etc. all return quickly and effectively.

Comment: The CPU time shown by Nodetime might eventually also include other activity, which happened during the call, for example other calls/callbacks or garbage collection. This is so due to single-threaded nature of Node. Although, if overall CPU usage is low, the shown CPU time might well correspond to the CPU time used by the call itself. CPU profiler could show it more precisely.

Comment: Any progress on the issue? I have encountered the same error